# dropdown menu doesn't open

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, view

I use an affix navbar, that stays fixed on top when scrolling down. I did a lot of changes yesterday, but now the dropdown menu won't open (or at least show)... I can't figure out where the problem lies.

Can anyone see it?

Sooooo: I testet some things. The problem seems to be, that I have following scripts at the end of the body:

```
<!------------------------------------------------------------ VENDOR JS -->
<script src="<?= DIR_VENDOR ?>jquery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= DIR_VENDOR ?>bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= DIR_VENDOR ?>slider/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

<!------------------------------------------------------------ SYSTEM JS -->
<script src="<?= DIR_LIBRARIES ?>js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="<?= $system['template']['web_path'] ?>script.js"></script>
```

I needed that for bootstrap slider to work. Can you tell me which ones I need to put back in the header again for the dropdown as well as the slider to work?

```css
/********************************************************************* HEADER */
div.header.container-fluid {
    width:                                              100%;
    background-image:                                   url(gfx/2.jpg);
    background-size:                                    cover;
    height: 85vh;
    background-attachment:                              fixed;   
}

/********************************************************************** AFFIX */
.affix + .container-fluid {
    padding-top:                                        70px;
  }  
.affix-top {
    background-color:                                   #db091a;    
  }
.affix-top a                                            {padding: 10px 15px 0px 15px !important;}
.affix {
    top:                                                0;
    width:                                              100%;
    -webkit-transition:                                 all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:                                         all .5s ease-in-out;
    background-color:                                   #3b3b3b;
    border-top:                                         3px solid #db091a;
}
.affix a {
    padding-top:                                        7px !important;
    -webkit-transition:                                 all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:                                         all .5s ease-in-out;
}
  
  
/********************************************************************* NAVBAR */

div.navbar.navbar-custom {     
    -webkit-box-shadow:                                 0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(77,74,77,1);
    -moz-box-shadow:                                    0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(77,74,77,1);
    box-shadow:                                         0px 2px 10px 0px rgba(77,74,77,1);
    border-radius:                                      0px;
    z-index:                                            1030;
}

/* HEADER */
a.header.navbar-brand {
    font-family:                                        Josefin Sans;   
    font-size:                                          45px;
    text-transform:                                     uppercase;
    color:                                              #FFF;
    line-height:                                        50px;
}

/* TOP */
ul.nav.navbar-nav.top                                   {float: right !important;}
a.top {
    font-family:                                        'Palanquin', sans-serif;
    text-transform:                                     uppercase;
    font-weight:                                        500;
    color:                                              white;
    padding:                                            0px;
    margin:                                             0px 0px 0px 30px;
    border-bottom:                                      3px solid transparent; 
}

/* USER */
a.dropdown-toggle.user                                  {padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px; margin-left: 20px;}
span.glyphicon.glyphicon-user {
    color:                                              #3b3b3b;
    background-color:                                   white;
    padding:                                            5px;
    font-size:                                          30px;
} 

/* DROPDOWN */
ul.dropdown-menu                                        {padding: 0px;}
div.collapse.navbar-collapse                            {padding: 0px;}
ul.nav.navbar-nav.bottom                                {float: right !important;}

a.dropdown-toggle.drop { 
    font-family:                                        'Palanquin', sans-serif;
    text-transform:                                     uppercase;
    font-weight:                                        500;
    color:                                              white;
    padding:                                            0px;
    margin:                                             0px 0px 5px 30px;
    border-bottom:                                      3px solid transparent;
}
a.dropdown-toggle.drop:hover                            {border-bottom: 3px solid #db091a;}
a.dropdown-toggle.drop:active                           {border-bottom: 3px solid #db091a;}
a.dropdown-toggle.drop:focus                            {border-bottom: 3px solid #db091a;}
```

```html
<!-- START: HEADER -->    
<div class="header container-fluid hidden-xs">
</div>   
    
<!-- START: NAVBAR -->


    <div class="navbar navbar-custom" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="500" id="anker">
        
        <div class="container-fluid">
           
            <div class="row" id="anchor">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <a class="header navbar-brand" href="#"><?= $language['phrases']['site_title']; ?></a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle " data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button> 
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">    
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle user" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user hidden-xs"></span> <span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl"> Benutzer <b class="caret"></b> </span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">beispiel1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">beispiel2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">beispiel3</a></li>               
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row2">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">   
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav bottom">   
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle drop" data-toggle="dropdown"> xMailer <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Advertiser</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kampagnen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Listen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Nodes</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle drop" data-toggle="dropdown">Administration <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Konfigurationen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Module</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Seiten</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gruppen</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Benutzer</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sprachen</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </li>      
                            </ul>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>   

        </div>  
    </div>    

    
<!-- END: NAVBAR -->
```

Comment: Hey can you make one fiddle for same ??

Answer (score 0):

ok problem solved!

the scripts in the html body were the reason for the missing dropdown menu!